# How to push a view from inside a UITableViewCell that is in a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UITableView` inside of a `UICollectionViewCell` and I'm trying to push a new view from the `UITableViewCell` inside of the `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` method. However, I cannot access `navigationController`. How would I go about navigating to the new view?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var item = Item(name: "")

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        item = array1![indexPath.item]
    case 1:
        item = array2![indexPath.item]
    default:
        break
    }

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let newView = NewCollectionView(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    newView.itemOfInterest = item

    // Can't reference navigationController
}
```

Comment: You can make your delegate method which will be fired in didSelect and it should be implemented in your viewcontroller where you can push.

Comment: You can also implement delete method of tableview delegate in to your ViewController. And You have also options of implement custom delegate which are called at your ViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Get parent controller of current View -*

```
//MARK: get parent controller...
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Usage:-**
Get navigationController reference as `parentViewController?.navigationController`

```
let viewController = GymLearnMoreViewController(nibName: "GymLearnMoreViewController", bundle: nil) //Your View controller instance
parentViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Source Apple:-

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621099-next
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder?changes=_9

Answer (score 0):

for this

1 . You need to declare a protocol in the collectionviewcell where the tableview is added

2 . implement the protocol method on the class where the collectionview is added. and handle the navigation on click from here

3 . set the collectionview cell delegate when the collectionviewCellForrow at indexpath method is invoked and call the delegate method when the tableview item is clicked within the collectionview cell

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `NotificationCenter` which you can write in `ParentViewController` :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(methodNavigate(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NavigateToSecondView"), object: nil)
}

@objc func methodNavigate(notification: NSNotification) {
    Write your push segue code here.
}
```

Don't forget to remove observer in `viewDidDisappear`:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NavigateToSecondView"), object: nil)
}
```

You can pass data through this too.

Then in `didSelectRowAt` :

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NavigateToSecondView"), object: "Send Data Here")
```

But I will suggest using protocol is much better and elegant way.
You can get lots of tutorials and samples on internet:

- https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/all-about-protocols-in-swift-11a72d6ea354
- https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html

Hope it helps. Happy coding.